# Old Version of Commons-HttpClient gives IOException in the Axis2 Web Service Client

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wsdl2java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using a wsdl2java generated web service client for the axis2 web service (axis2 version is 1.6.1). So for http connection the old version of commons-httpclient 3.1 is used. While doing some load tests to my web service client. In some cases i came across this exception

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axiom.ext.io.StreamCopyException: Error reading from source
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at com.ardic.arcsp.carbon.registry.ws.stub.WSStorageServiceStub.fromOM(WSStorageServiceStub.java:16706)
at com.ardic.arcsp.carbon.registry.ws.stub.WSStorageServiceStub.wSgetById(WSStorageServiceStub.java:6659)
at com.ardic.arcsp.update.wsclient.WSStorageServiceClient.getResourceById(WSStorageServiceClient.java:177)
at com.ardic.arcsp.update.wsclient.OTAUpdateTestServlet.downloadResource(OTAUpdateTestServlet.java:162)
at com.ardic.arcsp.update.wsclient.OTAUpdateTestServlet.doGet(OTAUpdateTestServlet.java:91)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:298)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:705)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: org.apache.axiom.ext.io.StreamCopyException: Error reading from source
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.impl.PartFactory.createPart(PartFactory.java:172)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.getPart(Attachments.java:705)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.getNextPartDataHandler(Attachments.java:623)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.getDataHandler(Attachments.java:350)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.OMAttachmentAccessorMimePartProvider.getDataHandler(OMAttachmentAccessorMimePartProvider.java:45)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPDecodingStreamReader$DataHandlerProviderImpl.getDataHandler(XOPDecodingStreamReader.java:81)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPDecodingStreamReader.getDataHandler(XOPDecodingStreamReader.java:472)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.getDataHandler(SwitchingWrapper.java:1360)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.XMLStreamReaderUtils.getDataHandlerFromElement(XMLStreamReaderUtils.java:230)
at com.ardic.arcsp.carbon.registry.ws.stub.xsd.WSResource$Factory.parse(WSResource.java:2087)
at com.ardic.arcsp.carbon.registry.ws.stub.WSgetByIdResponse$Factory.parse(WSgetByIdResponse.java:417)
at com.ardic.arcsp.carbon.registry.ws.stub.WSStorageServiceStub.fromOM(WSStorageServiceStub.java:16273)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.ext.io.StreamCopyException: Error reading from source
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.utils.BAAOutputStream.readFrom(BAAOutputStream.java:114)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.impl.BufferUtils.inputStream2OutputStream(BufferUtils.java:76)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.impl.PartFactory.createPart(PartFactory.java:136)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CRLF expected at end of chunk: 116/161
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.readCRLF(ChunkedInputStream.java:207)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:219)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:176)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.axiom.om.util.DetachableInputStream.read(DetachableInputStream.java:147)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:169)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.BoundaryPushbackInputStream.readFromStream(BoundaryPushbackInputStream.java:114)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.BoundaryPushbackInputStream.read(BoundaryPushbackInputStream.java:248)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.MIMEBodyPartInputStream.read(MIMEBodyPartInputStream.java:87)
at org.apache.axiom.attachments.utils.BAAOutputStream.readFrom(BAAOutputStream.java:112)
... 50 more
```

The web service client request files from the server and downloads the file. These exceptions occurs on the response while receiving files in chunks.
While searching i came across this fix mentioned here.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-190

However the exceptions still occur. So what else can cause this exceptions?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, i got the real reason for exception.On the client side if the memory allocation for jvm is low, the response from the server cannot be processed due to SocketTimeOut. But the exception itself could not stress this. Increasing the heap on the client side can solve the problem temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need enough memory to hold all the data that is chucked to the client. Java can give really weird results, especially the older JVMs, when there isn't enough memory to go around. It can be tricky sometimes to identify that as the root cause so bravo on that find.

There are a few helpful big on the [Apache Axis2 User's Guide - Creating Clients](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) page that might be helpful if you are new to wsdl2java.

Our next step is to learn [what command line options are available](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/WSDL2Java). One thing you can try is using the -u option to generate separate classes for the data bindings instead of creating them as inner classes. (Take a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136627/generate-separate-java-files-instead-of-a-single-stub-using-apache-axis2-from-ws).)

Since this question is 10 years old if you run into this or another error please create a new question specific to that context.