# Generate separate Java files instead of a single Stub using Apache Axis2 from WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

Currently, we are generating a single Stub from a given WSDL file using the following command:

```
wsdl2java -uri "filename.wsdl"
```

This generates a single Java Stub containing all the function calls etc. The problem is this time the size of the generated Java Stub is more than 20mb which makes it difficult to compile, debug and reuse.

Can someone suggest a method to generate segregated Java files instead of a single Stub.

Else can someone suggest some other method to handle large WSDL files via Java Web Services.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way of doing what you want, the best course of action here would be to seperate this huge service into a few smaller ones, so you'll have 2-3 WSDL files.

Comment: I also face this problem like you. Generated files too big, try putting some parametters at the end of command, try `-u` (**u**npack). Read reference document: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html#cmdref

Answer (score 2):

When generating the stub, *wsdl2java* normally generates the databinding classes as inner classes of the stub class. So all of your databinding classes are included in the stub class file, adding to the file's size.

The wsdl2java parameter `-u` causes it to generate the databinding classes as regular classes, each in its own file. That would reduce the size of the stub class file, though you'd still end up with the same amount of code overall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out another way... I used -xmlbeans databinding option to generate files, it generates separate class files now from the main stub... I remove the instance of all other classes that I don't need. This way I am able to reduce the size of jar.. and it is very useful when suppose you are trying to use only 10% of the wsdl service exposed and you want only those 10% of the class files in jar to be present in our lib directory.

Comment: @AurA , what is -xmlbeans ? How can we use this? Any pointer?

Comment: @AurA, I'm also getting over 45MB generated java classes when using wsdl2java for a web service. Could you let me know how you were able to make it smaller?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only manageable way is to make the wsdl generated classes as a separate module. So, it should be compiled once, placed into maven repository and then used as a `.jar`.

Also you could give a try to use the standard jaxws, or also CXF which is more powerful and modern, maybe it would generate the code better.

Comment: I am already doing that, can you suggest any other approach to handle large wsdl files.

Comment: @AurA And what you don't like about it? In worst case I need compile wsdl module once a month, usually I do it once for a service. Why is it problem then?